# В чем отличие чипсетов на wifi адаптере

Tags: linux, wifi, adapter, kali-linux, wlan

Есть два адаптера http://clc.to/fkq0Dw И http://clc.to/qNOP4A, есть ли различия в их чипсетах? Поддерживают ли они одинаковые функции в кали линукс(например режим монитор, wifi инекции)? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: нет различия между ними

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данных устройствах используется чипсет RTL8187. Разницы никакой. Всё зависит от софта и драйвера, которые будут в вашем распоряжении для работы.

Comment: Наивно так полагать без чтения спецификаций на чип.

Comment: На уровне драйвера, что есть в Kali Linux, разницы никакой

Comment: По всей видимости вам слово quirk не знакомо. И это ещё не говоря о прошивке «одинаковых» чипов.